# Override an @Embedded from a @MappedSuperclass

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0

I'm working with a legacy database and have no DDL privileges.

I created a `@MappedSuperclass` that have `@Embedded` attributes:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class MyEntity {
    @Embedded
    private CreateInfo createInfo;

    @Embedded
    private UpdateInfo updateInfo;
}
```

Unfortunately, one table has a different column name for the above properties.

Is it possible to override the attributes on the actual `Entity`, if yes how?

Comment: `@AttributeOverride` is what you use

Comment: @BillyFrost, Isn't ``@AttributeOverride`` for overriding basic attributes? But thanks for the hint, it's definitely worth a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that `@AttributeOverride` can be nested.

```
@Entity
@AttributeOverrides({
    @AttributeOverride(name = "updateInfo.lastModifiedBy", column = @Column(name = "DIFF_NAME1"))
  , @AttributeOverride(name = "updateInfo.lastModifiedDate", column = @Column(name = "DIFF_NAME2"))
})
public class Child extends MyEntity {...}
```